# Copy & Delete Sheet 2 and rename the Sheet 1 based on Cell Value in Sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, copy

My cell A1, A2, A3, A4,.... in Sheet 1 contain certain word. Example: A1="Work", A2="Schedule", A3 ="Cost", A4="Summary",..... and I introduce click button into Sheet 1.

What I want, when the button being click, it will copy Sheet 2 and rename it based on the word in cell in Sheet 1. Meaning once I click the button, 4 & more new sheet created and name as Work / Schedule / Cost / Summary/ , etc.

And if the I amend the cell in Sheet 1, example if I delete the word "Work" in cell A1, the Sheet "Work" that has been copied before will be delete as well when I click the button for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'Sheet 1' in OP is 'Sheet1'.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim oDic As Object, vKey, c As Range
    Dim sTxt As String, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Collect all expected sheet name, store in Dict
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each c In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            sTxt = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then oDic(UCase(sTxt)) = sTxt
        Next
    End With
    For Each oSht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        sTxt = UCase(oSht.Name)
        If Not (sTxt = "SHEET1" Or sTxt = "SHEET2") Then
            If oDic.exists(sTxt) Then
                oDic(sTxt) = ""
            Else
                ' Delete unknown sheet
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                oSht.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Loop through Dic
    For Each vKey In oDic
        If Len(oDic(vKey)) > 0 Then     ' non-exist sheet
            ' Copy and rename sheet
            Sheets("Sheet2").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = oDic(vKey)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create the add button  based on code below to add new sheet:

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners6_Click()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("6.1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("6")
With Sheets("6")
For Each c In .Range("C8:C" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
specifictext = "Insert"
        sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It works based on image below where the new sheet has been added follow value in cell from column C when I click the button.

[image]

Now there are two things I want:

1. If I click the button for second time, I want nothing to happen if the sheet based on name from column C already exist. Because right now, when I click the button, it will pop-up "Run-time error 1004: That name is already taken. Try a different one.
2. When I delete value "D1" which refer to cell C12, I want sheet D1 also be deleted when I click the button. and no effect to the cell the I delete the value.

Help if really appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Please implement all of code from below. My code have the logic to validate the sheet. You only get the part of it. That's reason why you got the run time error.